# Safe Method of Providing Bulk Images to Users?

Tags: html, image, api, cloudflare

I recently set up an API for users to pull information and it's been a huge success. 
The API returns information containing info such as **Name** and **ID**.
I then tell the user they can get the matching image by simply pulling the image from:

```
mysite.com/pics/ID_Retrieved_From_API.jpg
```

This has been working fine except today when I woke up to my site being completely down due to it hitting it's resource limit (shared hosting). I checked my logs an noticed a specific IP pulling thousands of my images:

```
[08/Feb/2019:07:06:54 +0000] "GET /pics/76600549.jpg HTTP/1.1" 508 224 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0"
[08/Feb/2019:07:06:54 +0000] "GET /pics/93700540.jpg HTTP/1.1" 508 224 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0"
[08/Feb/2019:07:06:54 +0000] "GET /pics/91000583.jpg HTTP/1.1" 508 224 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0"
[08/Feb/2019:07:06:54 +0000] "GET /pics/52300492.jpg HTTP/1.1" 508 224 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0"
[08/Feb/2019:07:06:54 +0000] "GET /pics/87400522.jpg HTTP/1.1" 508 224 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0"
[08/Feb/2019:07:06:54 +0000] "GET /pics/78400534.jpg HTTP/1.1" 508 224 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0"
[08/Feb/2019:07:06:54 +0000] "GET /pics/63100533.jpg HTTP/1.1" 508 224 "-" "python-requests/2.21.0"
```

I blocked the IP temporarily to bring my site back up. I'm not annoyed at the user since I pretty much encouraged this but I didn't except someone to pull the images so aggressively. 
I'm unsure how to proceed now. What would be an optimal way of allowing users to pull images? I was thinking of zipping them all together but the end result would be a file >5gb and I think that would still kill server resources.

I tried **rate limiting** in cloudflare but that didn't seem to work and when I unblocked the IP my resources maxed out again.
My rate limit rule was:

```
mysite.com/pics/*
10 requests per 1 second = Block
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution which is working nicely is to sign up to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and host the images for the API there in a bucket.

To avoid confusion, and to also potentially avoid this still happening in the future, I added `image_url` to my API which points at the Google Cloud Storage image location so users accessing the API can quickly grab the correct image URL for the API.

Finally, I set up [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=google%20cloud%20storage%20cors) (CORS) on the hosted image bucket so users can access the images.

This has been set up for roughly 5 days now and my site has had no issues since doing it. It's a solution that requires a cost but hosting images on Google Cloud Storage is actually rather [cheap](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).